# Free movement of drag and drop features on Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am creating a mobile app in Xamarin on Visual Studio 2017 (for Android). When designing the GUIs for my application I have noticed that dragging controls from the toolbox onto the screen is very static. It doesn't let me move controls to the centre and bottom of the screen for example:

[image]

I want to move this button to where the arrow points, however, Xamarin does not let me move the button out of the confines of that row and not in the centre of the screen. Anyone know how to make the movement of objects freer?

Thank you

Comment: What is the layout that the button is in? I don't use this tool to create pages, but I think that you can only move in layouts like RelativeLayout or AbsoluteLayout.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is probably not with the drag and drop and with the layout that you are using if you try using the RelativeLayout available in your toolbar menu and start dragging stuff then it would work.

Also, there are known bugs related to this issue on Bugzilla which you can check here :

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44359

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36689

https://www.telerik.com/forums/toolbox-controls-not-drag-drop-able